# Check the render method of 'HomeScreen'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, tailwind-css

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

HomeScreen code

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  UserIcon,
  ChevronDownIcon,
  SearchIcon,
  AdjustmentsIcon,
} from "react-native-heroicons/outline";
import Categories from "../components/Categories";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5 flex-col">
      {/* Header */}
      <View className="flex-row pb-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2 px-4">
        <Image
          source={{
            url: "https://links.papareact.com/wru",
          }}
          className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full"
        />
        <View className="flex-1">
          <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">Deliver Now !</Text>
          <Text className="font-bold text-xl">
            Current Location
            <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00cc88" />
          </Text>
        </View>

        <UserIcon size={35} color="#00cc88" />
      </View>

      {/* Search */}
      <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4 ">
        <View className="flex-row flex-1 space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3">
          <SearchIcon color="gray" size={20} />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Restros and Cuisines"
            keyboardType="default"
          />
        </View>

        <AdjustmentsIcon color="#00cc88" />
      </View>

      {/* Body */}
      <ScrollView
        className="bg-gray-100"
        contentContainerStyle={{
          paddingBottom: 100,
        }}
      >
        {/* Categories */}
        <Categories />
        {/* Featured Rows */}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

i don,t know what i particularly imported or exported wrong.
please help me out

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const Categories = () => {`enter code here`
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Categories</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Categories
```

Comment: try to import Categories like that : `import {Categories} from "../components/Categories";`

Comment: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. stuck here.

Comment: I tried almost every possible solution over stackoverflow , spent almost a day

Comment: show the code of ur component that might help

Comment: i don't see a problem in the component, try to upload ur project to snack and share the link

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@uv-07/5c1885

Comment: i'm a newbie, tried to put it on snack though :)

Answer (score 0):

struggled with the icons and got an error: Expected a string...something wrong with  export/import...etc.
youll have to search the names on heroicons website because they're different:
SearchIcon = MagnifyingGlassIcon
AdjustmentsIcon = AdjustmentsVerticalIcon

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so how I solved this was, replace `AdjustmentsIcon` with `AdjustmentsVerticalIcon` and your bug should be fixed. The reason for changing this is that if you search up the HeroIcons website for icons, and you type in `AdjustmentsIcon`, no icon filters out.
They apparently changed it to `AdjustmentsVerticalIcon`.